# How to create a Kibana Vertical bar chart with 2 fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have successfully integrated ELK stack which gets application log data from several sites and could create some Pie charts and Vertical bar charts. Now I am going to create a new Vertical bar chart but can't create according to my requirement.

I have two fields, `site_name` (include names of cities) and `action` (include web application actions like case created, case deleted, user login, user log out etc.). Each log statement will have these two parameters.

Now I want to create a Vertical Bar chart to display only number of cases created for each site based on `action` and `site_name`. That means y axis should be count of cases created based on action field and x axis should be the site name based on site_name field.

I tried to create a Vertical bar chart and when I choose Y axis aggregation as `Count` then I can't select the `action` as field. How can I create this chart ?

Thanks.!

Comment: @Pigueiras Do you think this kind of chart is possible in Kibana?

Comment: Maybe you should provide some actual data and logstash ingestion details.  Then this would be more like a stackoverflow kind of question